# A lightweight rich text editor with well formed HTML5 in Javascript?

Tags: open-source, javascript, web-development, jquery

To include in my website I need a rich text editor plugin (javascript) that transforms a normal textarea into a nice simple editor. In the past I've used FCKEditor / CKEditor which is great but a bit too much for my needs (too much code because it has too many features I don't require).

The editor will be used by my website visitors so I want to keep it simple with just a few common options like bold, italic, font-size, font color, a few types of font's and align paragraph.

So I'm looking for a plugin that is, in order of importance:

- good, simple UI for 'common users' (not admins)
- lightweight
- generates proper HTML5 code
- allows to customize the icons on the toolbar (remove/add features)
- free for commercial use

Nice to have: active community and easy to understand / change the code in case of need :)

It can be a jQuery plugin or plain Javascript. No plugins requiring bootstrap please (a good one I liked is https://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ but that seems to use bootstrap for styling)

Answer (score 1):

The alternative option is by using my simple *Rich Text Editor*.

[image: Rich Text Editor]

https://github.com/tovic/rich-text-editor

And as you were asked, it was designed to be used in a public text editor such as comment form and/or Q/A form in a forum.